# Android - /proc/cpuinfo returning different

Tags: android, cpu

I am working on an Android app in which I access `/proc/cpuinfo` file.
I am reading that file twice and am getting 2 different results ...

This does happen on the `LG G4 (Android 5.1 - API 22)` but not on the `Nexus 5 (Android 6 - API 23)`. App is built for API 22.

Here are the results:

**First time:**

```
Processor   : AArch64 Processor rev 3 (aarch64)
processor   : 0
processor   : 1
processor   : 2
processor   : 3
processor   : 4
processor   : 5
Features    : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 3

Hardware    : Qualcomm Technologies, Inc MSM8992
Revision    : 000b
```

**Second time:**

```
Processor   : AArch64 Processor rev 3 (aarch64)
processor   : 0
processor   : 1
processor   : 2
processor   : 3
processor   : 4
processor   : 5
Features    : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant : 0x1
CPU part    : 0xd07
CPU revision    : 2

Hardware    : Qualcomm Technologies, Inc MSM8992
Revision    : 000b
```

I then have done a `adb shell cat proc/cpuinfo` which has returned the same result as the **first time**

This is really annoying for what I am doing. Do you guys have any idea why this happens ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The execution thread may be secluded on different core. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_big.LITTLE